# Pandas to_csv overwrite instead of append

Tags: python, flask

This is my flask application - https://replit.com/@WebScrapers/Job-Search
The data in the csv file gets appended each time search is clicked. How should I make it to overwrite instead of append?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html - You can check the argument 'mode' here. 'w' will overwrite a csv, 'a' will append to a csv.

Comment: I fixed it. I had a bug in my program